# I do not know why I am getting a System.IndexOutOfRangeException? C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public static KeyValuePair<string[], string[]> GetAccounts()
{   
    string[] usernames = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };
    string[] oauths = { "oauth1", "oauth2", "oauth3" };
    return new KeyValuePair<string[], string[]> (usernames, oauths);
}
```

And then I am calling the function in Main():

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    KeyValuePair<string[], string[]> users = GetAccounts ();
    for (int i = 0; i <= users.Key.Length; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine (i);
        Console.WriteLine (users.Key.GetValue (i) + " " + users.Value.GetValue (i));
   }
```

}

However, when I get a System.IndexOutOfRangeException on the second console write line. I have no idea why this does not work. I am expecting to see:

```
 user1 oauth1
 user2 oauth2
 user3 oauth3
```

Comment: it should be smaller than the length, not smaller or equal (as the length would be 2 but the last index available is 1 (0, 1 = 2 items)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should use `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i < users.Key.Length; i++)`

Change <= to < in the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

the variable `i` cannot be equal to `users.Key.Length`.

Change `for (int i = 0; i <= users.Key.Length; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < users.Key.Length; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException because your for loops run 4 times  instead of three and in the last loop it searches for users.Key.GetValue(3) which is not present.

You can use below code to rectify

```
  for (int i = 0; i < users.Key.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine (i);
            Console.WriteLine (users.Key.GetValue (i) + " " + users.Value.GetValue (i));
       }
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= users.Key.Length-1; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine (i);
            Console.WriteLine (users.Key.GetValue (i) + " " + users.Value.GetValue (i));
       }
```